# Disable Select of Single Origin and House Blend when user choose Esspresso

Tags: javascript, html, web

```
<td>
           <select class="type">
               <option value="Espresso">Espresso</option>
               <option value="" class="">Cappuccino</option>
               <option value="" class="">Americano</option>
               <option value="" class="">Pour over</option>
               <option value="Chemex" onChange="disableSize()" class="Chemex" id ="Chemex">Chemex</option>
           </select>
       </td>
       <td>
           <select class="coffe">
               <option value="" class="es">House espresso</option>
               <option value="" class="esp">Guest espresso</option>
               <option value="" class="ori">Single origin</option>
               <option value="" class="house">House blend</option>
           </select>
       </td> 

let  es = document.querySelector(".type")
es.addEventListener("change2",() => {
    if (es.value == "Espresso") {
        document.querySelectorAll(".ori", ".house").disabled = true;
    } else{
        document.querySelectorAll(".ori", ".house").disabled = false;
}
}, false)
```

I would like to disable slection of Single origin and House blend when user choose Esspresso in class type so you can only able to choose House Esspresso and guest Esspresso. This is my JavaScript line of code, It didn't worked please hep me.

Comment: `"change2"` ...?

Comment: I set my name function = change2 ?

Comment: There's no named function here.  You're setting a function to handle the "change2" event, and I'm not aware of any such event.  (Unless you're using a custom plugin that defines it.)  Basically it looks like the problem here is just a typo in the "change" event name.

Comment: `disableSize` function doesn't exist in the example? `change2` is not a standard event name and the example does not create the custom event?

Comment: You're also passing multiple parameters to `document.querySelector`, which takes one parameter.  **Edit:** And now you just changed the code to use `querySelectorAll`, the return value of which has no `disabled` property.  Overall, you seem to be somewhat randomly writing things in your code...

Comment: Why is `onChange` on the option element? I don't think it will do anything.

Comment: It is from another function of mine, sorry for confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call checkValue function on load to check the current value and then on change to check the new value and perform the action to the selected value type

```js
let  es = document.querySelector(".type")
checkValue();
es.addEventListener("change",() => {

   checkValue();
})

function checkValue(){
        var isDisabled = (es.value == "Espresso");
        document.querySelector(".ori").disabled = isDisabled;
        document.querySelector(".house").disabled = isDisabled;
    
}
```

```html
<td>
           <select class="type">
               <option value="Espresso">Espresso</option>
               <option value="" class="">Cappuccino</option>
               <option value="" class="">Americano</option>
               <option value="" class="">Pour over</option>
               <option value="Chemex" onChange="disableSize()" class="Chemex" id ="Chemex">Chemex</option>
           </select>
       </td>
       <td>
           <select class="coffe">
               <option value="es" class="es">House espresso</option>
               <option value="esp" class="esp">Guest espresso</option>
               <option value="" class="ori">Single origin</option>
               <option value="" class="house">House blend</option>
           </select>
       </td>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of False in es.addEventListener("change",() => {
   checkValue();
}, false)

Comment: I would replace the innards of checkValue with `document.querySelector(".ori").disabled = (es.value == "Espresso");
document.querySelector(".house").disabled = (es.value == "Espresso");
`. There is no reason to query the value of a boolean to set another boolean.

Comment: @PalleDue thanks buddy to help improve the answer

Comment: @AbdulMoiz: You're welcome. Your code is totally correct, and some would claim it's more readable, but it's a bit of a pet peeve for me. ;-)